# Qt Creator - Not Getting Function Argument Hints For Some OpenCV Constructors

Tags: qt, opencv, qt-creator

I'm working with OpenCV in Qt Creator and everything is running fine. There is just this one problem that I don;t get function argument hints for some OpenCV constructors like `cv::Size()` and `cv::Point()`. I do however get argument hints for all functions of OpenCV. is there something that can be done about this? I do get argument hints for these in Visual Studio though.

Comment: @KeillRandor roger that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some versions of QtCreator the autocompletion does not work with `typedef` type objects. This bug [was reported](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-8248) time ago, but I am not sure that it has been fixed (at least, it doesn't work for me in v3.1.0). `Point`, `Size` and `Rect` are examples of typedef variables (they are `typedef`s from `Point_<int>`, `Size_<int>` and `Rect_<int>` respectively) with which autocompletion does not work.

If at anytime you forget the constructor parameters, what I do is writing any of the template names (`Point_`, `Rect_` or `Size_`) and QtCreator will autocomplete :)